# Web browser pauses a setTimeout which causes glitches on my page when PC is in deep sleep or revisiting the page on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript

Usually I post code on my posts but i'm just curios in general with this question on my mind so here's the situation. I have a couple of real time systems which uses one file that produces constant basic polling with CRUD(Create,Read,Update and Delete) traits. The way i'm doing this is

by putting the setTimeout at the end of that page which constantly call a function on the main page to recall that page AKA the polling with CRUD page by AJAX which also constantly analyze different components of the main web page and executes one of the CRUD traits depending on the logic of

the situation between the web page and the database, I know web browsers pauses a setTimeout on purpose for the purpose of saving computing energy when that web page is not being interacted with due to the following situations that I notice

for example on PC when a user revisits that kind of system when revisiting that web page after coming back from the lock screen or when revisiting that web page after coming back from the login page or when revisiting that web page after

coming back from a sleep state and even revisiting that web page after coming back from another web tab after long periods of time and on mobile browsers, when revisiting that web page after coming back from the lock screen or when

revisiting that web page after coming back from another app or when revisiting that web page after coming back from a sleep state. All these situations causes my real time polling with CRUD system to experience glitches but no glitches occurs if I remain on the page so I was just

wondering is there any JavaScript methods that I can use as response code to detect when a browser pauses a web page like this on PC or on Mobile devices like smart phones or tablets? I was thinking if there is a method like that. I can simply just

create a response code that can reload that web page if the browser does that.

Comment: There is this, YMMV ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: "is there any JavaScript methods that I can use as response code to detect a when a browser pauses a web page" ....think about that for a second: if the browser has paused the web page, then how would any such JavaScript be executed? The page is already paused, which is already preventing any scripts from running... If you could do the thing you're suggesting, you wouldn't need it in the first place.

Comment: "All these situations causes my real time polling with CRUD system to experience glitches" ....what specific problems are you experiencing? Maybe you can actually make your page (and/or server-side code) more resilient to the situation rather than trying to work round the browser's standard behaviour. However it's hard to give any advice if we don't know the exact nature of the problems.

Comment: One thing, if you're doing constant polling via AJAX then maybe overall a solution using WebSockets might actually suit your situation better, so you have constant two-way communication from browser to server and back again. Then you have a constantly open channel. I'm not sure precisely what happens when the page is paused by the browser, but it might be easier to deal with, and overall your page would probably perform better too, rather than making constant ajax calls.